# ionic 3 app show image on browser but dont on android device

Tags: android, ionic-framework, device

Thanks for any help, and sorry about my bad English, we speak Portuguese on my country...

ionic 3 app show remote image provided by api on browser with ionic serve but dont on android device, debug on chrome get this error: 
 7fa1ea1d73789d207ef51e6941913d5e_image.jpg:1 GET http://localhost:1337/parse/files/myAppId/7fa1ea1d73789d207ef51e6941913d5e_image.jpg net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

any help...

Comment: It looks like your android device has connection issues. So, the problem is not related to the image. I would suggest you focus on connectivity issues on your android.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have use relative paths for images like `<img src="../assets/imgs/logo.png">`
Don’t use relative paths for images instead use absolute paths like`<img src="assets/imgs/logo.png">`
Please refer below link for more details:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/images-not-displayed-on-device/89145

Answer (score 0):

If you want yo use localhost images when running on the device with ionic run android ——device —lc you should use your api address instead. You can see it with the command ipconfig in your terminal

Comment: i use localhost because my cms run on my laptop and my android device is connected on same network, so the ip address is not the problem because other data provided by my api is load successful thanks to reply